# call userDefults from another class (Swift4)

Tags: ios, class, swift4, nsuserdefaults

I would like my code to be be able to call the user Default in viewController and display its action in twoViewController if possible. So I would like both class backgrounds to be red if and only if the action was implemented in class viewController.

```
 import UIKit

 class ViewController: UIViewController {
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

@IBAction func press () {
  view.backgroundColor = .red
  UserDefaults.standard.set(view.backgroundColor, forKey: “userlogin”)
}
  }
class twoViewController: UIViewController {

//load Userdefults from class ViewController in view did load
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in viewController set:

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: UIColor.red as Any)
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "userlogin")
```

and in twoViewController:

```
if let data = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userlogin") as? Data, let color = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? UIColor{
        self.view.backgroundColor = color
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could register a notification for update the background color of twoViewController .

```
@IBAction func press () {
  view.backgroundColor = .red
  UserDefaults.standard.set(view.backgroundColor, forKey: “userlogin”)
  UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
  Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
}
```

Register a notification for updating UI

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: 
  #selector(self.methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: 
    Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

And add refresh code in function

```
@objc func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: Notification){
   // refresh UI code
   // load the color value
   // set up new value to background color
 }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers in what function do I put NOtificationCenter?

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() { }